# Replacing the =~ operator check in the if statement

Tags: bash

I have the following check:

```
if [[ "$abc" =~ ^((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\.com(:[0-9]+)?\/([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\.git)(\/)?$ ]]; then
   die "Invalid"
fi
```

It does not really matter what it checks, I just want to get rid of the `=~` operator. I have a basic static test of the scripts:

```
for file in $filelist
do
  echo -n "Checking $file..."
  bash -n $file
  echo "OK"
done
```

Due to the `=~` operator, it gets an error:

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
script: line 847: syntax error near `^(('
```

Even though, when I execute the script itself, I don't get that error.
I guess the error is due to not wrapping `^((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\.com(:[0-9]+)?\/([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\.git)(\/)?$` with apostrophes. If I do wrap it, it will not enter the `if` statement.
So I'm looking to replace the `=~`. What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I put your check in a file `foo` and ran `bash -n foo` and it completed without errors.

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry, I thought it was a problem with `=~` and not a problem with the regex itself. I updated the full regex. It a problem with the regex?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with this new regex as well.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not sure why but I get this behavior. Is it possible to use that regex with the apostrophes?

Comment: Can you please try it with just your 3 line check and your 6 line test loop? I.e. keep your existing 850+ line scripts out of it and just use what you've posted to ensure that the post contains all relevant information

Comment: Are you sure you are running your script with `bash`? [The code you posted works](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FavoritePassionateCommercialsoftware)

Comment: @vesii You can't put the regexp in quotes, that makes it do a literal comparison instead of a pattern match.

Comment: I removed all lines and left only the three lines and still get the error. Maybe it is because the test script is a separated file?

Comment: `[\w\.]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You also do not need to escape forward slashes; they have no special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: To debug this, start by replacing the large regular expression with something simpler: `[[ $abc =~ ^(git|ssh|https?) ]]`. If that works, slow add to the regular expression until you get your first error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `egrep -q` instead:

```
if [[ "$abc" =~ ^((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\.com(:[0-9]+)?\/([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\.git)(\/)?$ ]]; then
   die "Invalid"
fi
```

becomes:

```
if  
    egrep -q "^((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\.com(:[0-9]+)?\/([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\.git)(\/)?$ ]]" <<< "$abc"
then
   die "Invalid"
fi
```

`egrep -q` will return true (exit code of 0) if the regexp matches stdin (in this case we are using $abc as the stdin input.

I used egrep because you have an or expression in there (the pipes).

To be honest, I haven't tested this code, but I've used the `-q` option before with grep.  You'll need to make sure that your regexp is correct.

Comment: Only hit with `egrep` (or any utility) would depend on how many times the `if` is called. If it is called in a loop that iterates 1M times, then that would add 1M subshells spawned dramatically slowing the script. If it's a one-off, then no issue at all.